# std::enable_if or SFINAE for iterator or pointer

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, sfinae, enable-if

I would like to write a constructor for `MyClass` that take an argument and I want this to compile only if the argument is a `pointer` or an `iterator` (something having `iterator_traits`). How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regrettably, there is no standard way to detect whether a class models `Iterator`.  The simplest check would be that `*it` and `++it` are both syntactically valid; you can do this using standard SFINAE techniques:

```
template<typename T,
    typename = decltype(*std::declval<T&>(), void(), ++std::declval<T&>(), void())>
    MyClass(T);
```

Considering the `Iterator` requirements from 24.2.2:2:

```
template<typename T> typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_void<decltype(*std::declval<T &>())>::value
    && std::is_same<decltype(++std::declval<T &>()),
                    typename std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type>::value,
    std::true_type>::type has_iterator_requirements_helper(int);
template<typename T> std::false_type has_iterator_requirements_helper(...);
template<typename T> struct has_iterator_requirements:
    decltype(has_iterator_requirements_helper<T>(0)) {};

template<typename, bool> struct is_iterator_check: std::false_type {};
template<typename T> struct is_iterator_check<T, true>: std::true_type {
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T>::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category iterator_category;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T>::reference reference;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T>::pointer pointer;
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(*std::declval<T &>()), reference>::value
        || std::is_void<reference>::value, "*r must be of type reference");
};
template<typename T> struct is_iterator: is_iterator_check<T,
    (std::is_pointer<T>::value
     && !std::is_void<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::value
     && !std::is_function<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::value
     ) || (std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value
     && std::is_copy_assignable<T>::value
     && std::is_nothrow_destructible<T>::value
     // TODO: check lvalues are swappable
     && has_iterator_requirements<T>::value
     )> {};
```

The problem with trying to use `iterator_traits` is that it is a template defined for all types, and its instantiation will fail in a non-SFINAE context (recall that SFINAE only applies for direct substitution failure).  libstdc++ has a [conforming extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/libstdc++/api/a01471_source.html#l00143) whereby instantiating `iterator_traits` on non-iterator types will produce an empty type; you can do a similar trick by checking for the existence of `iterator_category` on the type:

```
template<typename T> std::true_type has_iterator_category_helper(
    T::iterator_category *);
template<typename T> std::false_type has_iterator_category_helper(...);
template<typename T> struct has_iterator_category<T>:
    decltype(has_iterator_category_helper<T>(0)) { };
template<typename T> struct is_iterator: std::integral_constant<bool,
    std::is_pointer<T>::value || has_iterator_category<T>::value> {};

template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if<is_iterator<T>::value>>
    MyClass(T);
```

This will however *not work* for types that do not themselves expose `iterator_category` but have been adapted by a separate `iterator_traits` specialisation; in that case the simple SFINAE method makes more sense (and you can instantiate `iterator_traits` within the constructor to confirm that the type is iterator-like).

Comment: @LucDanton agreed, I've put the SFINAE in as a preferred technique.

Comment: Great answer, you saved me explaining the extension we use in libstdc++ :)  See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40497 for the background to that extension. The credit for the idea of checking for `iterator_category` goes to Alisdair Meredith.

Comment: Mmmh, the requirements of `*it` is that the type be `std::iterator_traits<It>::reference`; not that it is a reference type (at least for Iterator). But you can't use `std::iterator_traits` for fear of messing up SFINAE... I'll let you fix that one! (You also have problems again with the value category of some expressions you test; e.g. `++std::declval<T&>()`, not `T`.)

Comment: @LucDanton the standard is inconsistent on `*r`; for `OutputIterator` `reference` is allowed to be `void`, which conflicts with `*r = o`.  I've put that in as a confirmation check.

Comment: why is void() in there twice?

Comment: @sp2danny it's to guard against any possible abuse of the comma operator, since an overloaded comma operator can't take `void` as a parameter type.