# Can't use function name distance

Tags: c++

The following code compiles fine:

```
#include <string>

int dist(std::string& a, std::string& b) {
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  std::string a, b;
  dist(a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

But when I rename the function from dist to distance:

```
#include <string>

int distance(std::string& a, std::string& b) {
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  std::string a, b;
  distance(a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

I get this error when compiling (gcc 4.2.1):

```
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h: In instantiation of ‘std::iterator_traits<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >’:
b.cpp:9:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:129: error: no type named ‘iterator_category’ in ‘struct std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >’
```

Why can't I name the function distance?

Comment: I knew right away what the problem was. If only I was here 3 hours earlier. Lol

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The reason is that a standard algorithm called [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) exists, which is found by ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup): although your call is not qualified with the `std` namespace, the type of your arguments `a` and `b` (i.e. `std::string`) lives in the same namespace as the `std::distance` function (i.e. `std`), and therefore `std::distance()` is also considered for overload resolution.

If you really want to call your function `distance()` (I'd suggest you not to), you can either put it in a namespace of yours, and then fully qualify the function name when you call it, or leave it in the global namespace and invoke it this way:

```
    ::distance(a, b);
//  ^^
```

Notice, however, that ADL alone might *not* cause your program to fail compiling if your implementation of the Standard Library provides a SFINAE-friendly version of `iterator_traits` (more details in [this Q&A on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161109/stdenable-if-or-sfinae-for-iterator-or-pointer) - courtesy of [MooingDuck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845092/mooing-duck)).

With a SFINAE-friendly implementation of `iterator_traits`, your compiler should recognize that the `std::distance()` function template (because it is a template) cannot be instantiated when given arguments of type `std::string`, because of its return type:

```
template< class InputIt >
typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type 
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//       Trying to instantiate this with InputIt = std::string
//       may result in a soft error during type deduction if
//       your implementation is SFINAE-friendly, and in a hard
//       error otherwise.
    distance( InputIt first, InputIt last );
```

In this case, the compiler would simply discard this template for the purposes of overload resolution and pick your `distance()` function.

However, if your implementation of the Standard Library does not provide a SFINAE-friendly version of `iterator_traits`, substitution failure may occur in a context that does not qualify for SFINAE, thus resulting in a (hard) compilation error.

This [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=a4471adfc1fce0eb5b920a44645546b7-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc) shows your original program compiling with GCC 4.8.0, which comes with a version of libstdc++ that implements a SFINAE-friendly `iterator_traits`.

Comment: Shouldn't this only be a problem if `using namespace std;` appears though?

Comment: So I just have to pick another name? There is no way to name my function distance?

Comment: @egoard: I'd suggest you to pick another name, yes. But if you really want to keep `distance()`, then you may qualify the call by explicitly telling the compiler that you want the function `distance()` that lives in the global namespace (as suggested in the last edit to my answer)

Comment: @TimothyShields: No, this is because of Argument Dependent Lookup

Comment: Enjoy the ADL uncertainty principle -- cases like this are the reason of many attempts to fix or tame this feature, but this far bounced. I suggest biting the bullet and use a different name. Those using CamelCase are fortunate to dodge mass of the issue.

Comment: @AndyProwl Ugh... I didn't even know this [ADL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) existed. It seems like a really bad feature!

Comment: @BalogPal: How does CamelCase affect the user's distance name?  My understanding is CamelCase only differs when concatenating words together.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: all names is std:: are all lowercase. If your name convention use mixed case you can't clash with std::.

Comment: @TimothyShields: It is not *that* bad, it also exists for good reasons. But yes, there are pitfall. Also, see my last edit to the answer: the program itself should compile even though `std::distance()` is being considered. The compiler is probably too old to know about SFINAE

Comment: @egoard: Perhaps you should also consider updating your compiler (see my last edit to the answer).

Comment: @AndyProwl: Oh, you're right.  I always thought `std::iterator_traits` prevented SFINAE from working right because of the way it's designed, but I guess not.

Comment: @Downvoter: Could you please leave a comment? I would like to know how I can improve my answer

Comment: @MooingDuck: Actually, reading that answer your linked, I think you may be right. stdlib++ has an implementation that is SFINAE-friendly, but the Standard does not mandate it. I'm going to edit the answer, thank you

Comment: @TimothyShields, If it didn't exist, `std::cout << "Hello, world!";` wouldn't compile.

Comment: @TimothyShields, Well, assuming you didn't do `using namespace std;` or `using std::operator<<`. Anyway, yeah, doing `std::operator<<(std::cout, "Hello, world!");` or `std::cout.operator<<("Hello, world!");` would be annoying.

Comment: @chris Well, as far as I can see, this means ADL is useful for operator overloading and annoying for function overloading.

Comment: @milleniumbug, But operators are just function calls.

Comment: @chris Well, that's a shame ;)